# Cassandra - ubuntu 16.04 :: Failed to start cassandra.service: Unit cassandra.service not found

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, cassandra, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using **ubuntu 16.04**.I was trying to install **Cassandra**. But I'm getting some unknown issues. Could you please help me to solve it.

I followed the **Apache-Cassandra** [Instructions](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#installation-from-debian-packages) to install **Cassandra 3.6**

I installed **python 2.7** on this machine.

When I use the command to see the status.

```
sudo service cassandra status
```

I'm getting this error

```
Cassandra.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I'm pretty sure, I was not doing as `root`.

I installed Cassandra in ubuntu 14.04 before one year without any problem. And worked well on different projects. Now getting these issues.

If I use the following command

```
sudo service cassandra start
```

I'm getting this error.

```
Failed to start cassandra.service: Unit cassandra.service not found.
```

Is there any problem with python and Cassandra version? Please help to solve these issues. Please suggest me the best way.

Answer (score 6):

Try to reinstall Cassandra via next commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge cassandra
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cassandra
```

And use the latest version of Cassandra - 3.9, because the previous has a problem with cqlsh if you have Python 2.7.11+.